# return correct value from list of widgets in Pyside2

Tags: python, pyside2, raspberry-pi4

I've been having this problem for several days and I can't find a way to fix it. I haven't found much help on the web either :(

I have a database with information about some elements. The query returns a dictionary with data like
`{'title': 'value', 'description': 'value', etc...}`

With each element I want to display it in a PySide2 layout, like so:

```py
import PySide2 # I'm simplifying imports for the sake of synthesis 
from ui_main import Ui_MainWindow

class MainWindow(QMainWindow):

    def __init__(self):
        super(MainWindow, self).__init__()
        self.ui = Ui_MainWindow()
        self.ui.setupUi(self)
        global widgets
        widgets = self.ui

        # set home
        widgets.nuevoProyectoButton.clicked.connect(self.buttonClick)
        self.display_elements()

    def display_elements(self):

        widgets.elementslayout = QGridLayout() # already tested with QVBoxLayout with no success
        widgets.elementslayout.setVerticalSpacing(10)
        widgets.elementslayout.setHorizontalSpacing(10)
        widgets.elementslayout.setContentsMargins(0, 0, 0, 0)
        widgets.elementslayout.setObjectName("elementslayout")
    
        elements_ids = [1, 2, 3, 4] # I retrieve this info from the database
    
        for element_id in elements_id:
            # some process
            img = QPixmap(img_path)
            label = QLabel()
            label.setPixmap(img)
            label.setObjectName(f"element_{element_id}")
    
            # Display element name in the grid
            abel2 = QLabel()
            label2.setText(f'<h3>{element_name}</h3> [{num_imagenes} imágenes]\n{element_description}')
            label2.setObjectName(f"element_name_{element_id}")
            widgets.elementslayout.addWidget(label2, id, 0)
        
            button = QPushButton()
            # button.setText("Añadir imágenes")
            button.setObjectName(f"edit_element_{element_id}")
            button.clicked.connect(lambda: self.set_scanner_page(element_id))
            widgets.elementslayout.addWidget(button, element_id, 1)
    
            button2 = QPushButton()
            button2.setObjectName(f"edit_element_{element_id}")
            button2.clicked.connect(self.dosomething)
            widgets.elementslayout.addWidget(button2, element_id, 2)

        widgets.verticalLayout_20.addLayout(widgets.elementslayout)
```

The elements are displayed correctly, but, and here's my issue, when I click any button it always returns me to the same `element_id`. In fact, it's always the last one in the `elements_ids`  list (in this case, each button returns me id number 4).

I tryed to use `.sender()` but it returns nothing.

How can I get each button to return the corresponding `element_id`?

Comment: In your code there's no declaration of `element_id`, and it also has terrible indentation problems. In any case, change to `lambda _, element_id=element_id: self.set_scanner_page(element_id)`

Comment: Thanks! I fixed the indentation :) I implemented your solution but now I get this error: `TypeError: <lambda>() missing 1 required positional argument: '_'`

Comment: Sorry, I forgot about that PySide aspect. Try `lambda element_id=element_id: self.set_scanner_page(element_id)` or `button.clicked[bool].connect(lambda _, element_id=element_id: self.set_scanner_page(element_id))`

Comment: Great! `button.clicked[bool].connect(lambda _, element_id=element_id: self.set_scanner_page(element_id))` did the trick! :)